# UICollectionView is not appearing

Tags: ios, swift

When i build my project (simulator/device) UICollectionView is not appearing.

I set (i think so) all delegates,functions etc. And i still dont have that view.

```
class WeatherViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource{


    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!


    var forecast: Forecast!
    var forecasts = [Forecast]()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!) -> Int{
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return forecasts.count
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ForecastCell", for: indexPath) as? ForecastCollectionViewCell {
            let forecast = forecasts[indexPath.row]
            cell.updateForecastCell(forecast: forecast)
            return cell
        } else {
            return ForecastCollectionViewCell()
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Check the count of `forecasts ` array.

Comment: Is correct, Im downloading date from JSON. I checked it. Everything is ok

Comment: Add a couple `print()` statements to confirm the `.count` and to confirm that `cellForItemAt` is being called as you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded the project and removed the `dataSource` and the `delegate` from `storyboard` because you set them already inside code.

You work with `Stack Views`. When I move your `collectionView` out of the `Stack Views` your code works as expected.

Unfortunately I don't know why you can't put a `collectionView` inside `Stack View`. Maybe you will find a solution then please post.

(My personal opinion: I really don't like `Stack Views`. It seems that they make you life easier but I can't apply with that.)
[image]